# Excel SUMIF - If OFFSET condition is met then SUM two OFFSET cells in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table like this:

```
TABLE A

NAME     VALUE 1   VALUE 2   RESULT
Daniel   1         4
John     3         5
Daniel   5         8
```

I need to run a SUMIF within the RESULT column that will check the above cells (Using OFFSET) and if a condition is met, I’d like both (OFFSET) VALUES to be added. I know I can achieve this by doing two SUMIFs, but I’d like to know if is it possible to do it using only one and then make my code more readable and fast. I've tried these with no luck:

```
SUMIF(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($A$2),1), "Daniel", SUM(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($B$2),1),OFFSET($C$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($C$2),1)))
```

And:

```
IF(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($A$2),1)="Daniel", SUM(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($B$2),1),OFFSET($C$2,0,0,ROW()-ROW($C$2),1),0)
```

The result should be:

```
TABLE A

NAME     VALUE 1   VALUE 2   RESULT
Daniel   1         4         0
John     3         5         5
Daniel   5         8         5
John     1         5         18
```

Answer (score 1):

Offset is not needed if not using structured table references:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:A1,"Daniel",$B$1:B1)+SUMIF($A$1:A1,"Daniel",$C$1:C1)
```

[image]

if you want one formula then it will be an array formula:

```
 =SUM(IF($A$1:A1="Daniel",$B$1:B1+$C$1:C1,0))
```

Depending on one's version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If one is use structured references to a true table then yes Offset is required:

```
=SUM(IF(OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[NAME]],,,ROW($ZZ1))="Daniel",OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[VALUE 1]],,,ROW($ZZ1))+OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[VALUE 2]],,,ROW($ZZ1)),0))
```

Again, depending on one's version this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Always wondered if using array formulas decreases processing speed, what's your thought on this?

Comment: Yes it does and should be used strategically.

Comment: Ok, i guess in this case will be better to use the first solution you provided even when it requires two SUMIF or it will be the same than an array formula?

Comment: It will be a little quicker.

Comment: Ok, even tho i need to put 7 SUMIFS (with same condition) to achieve what i need in same formula?

Comment: If it were me I would use a helper column that sums the 7 columns then you can use a single sumif.

Comment: thats why i ask the master! :)
slowly i'll learn to be creative in Excel too.
thanks!